# How to parse XML elements via T-SQL?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have an XML file that I am trying to break down into a table using SSMS 2008.  The XML file consists of various elements.
This is its structure.  How do I extract this data into tables?

```
<course>
  <lesson id="I00C8A1A645094C819BC9A0EBE2563E27">
    <element name="cmi.core.student_name">Michael,Robin</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.student_id">73Y4TZ0000K0</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.credit">credit</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.lesson_mode">normal</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.lesson_status">completed</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.entry" />
  </lesson>
  <lesson id="I66BCB22712934777BE7EB16468D43F7A">
    <element name="cmi.core.student_name">Michael,Robin</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.student_id">73Y4TZ0000K0</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.credit">credit</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.lesson_mode">normal</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.lesson_status">completed</element>
    <element name="cmi.core.entry" />
  </lesson>
```

One more note is that the above record comes from just one column.  For simplicity, assume there are only two columns.  Column 1 is a uniqueidentifier, with values: "C00707", "C00708","C00709", etc.  Each row has a record similar to above for Column 2.  So I just need to break this Column 2 down, element by element, row by row.

Comment: Could you provide desired table output from above XML?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  ID,
  T.N.value('(element[@name="cmi.core.student_name"])[1]',  'nvarchar(max)') as student_name,
  T.N.value('(element[@name="cmi.core.student_id"])[1]',    'nvarchar(max)') as student_id,
  T.N.value('(element[@name="cmi.core.credit"])[1]',        'nvarchar(max)') as credit,
  T.N.value('(element[@name="cmi.core.lesson_mode"])[1]',   'nvarchar(max)') as lesson_mode,
  T.N.value('(element[@name="cmi.core.lesson_status"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as lesson_status
from YourTable
  cross apply XMLCol.nodes('/course/lesson') as T(N)
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68820)